# scipy.optimize three variables and hundreds of solutions

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to use scipy to find the values of three variables (x,y,z) in a nonlinear equation of the type:

```
g(x) * h(y) * k(z) = F
```

where F is a vector with hundreds of values.

I successfully used scipy.optimize.minimize where F only had 3 values, but that failed when the size of F was greater than 3.

How can I find (x,y,z) using all values in F?

Here the code:

```
import numpy as np

#  Inputs:
thetas = np.array([25.4,65,37,54.9,26,21.3,24.1,35.7,46.1,61.1,57.2,41.9,20.5,24,55.6,56.9,42.2,39.9,30.8,59,28.8])
thetav = np.array([28.7,5.4,22.6,14.4,23.5,25,12.8,31.2,15.3,9,7.4,24.4,29.7,15.3,15.5,26.8,8.8,16.6,25.1,18.5,12])
azs =    np.array([130.3,158,150.2,164.8,152.4,143.5,144.2,151.8,167.4,169.7,162.2,161.4,138.2,147.8,172.9,168.6,158.3,159.8,151.7,160.8,144.5])
azv =    np.array([55.9,312.8,38.6,160.4,324.2,314.5,236.3,86.1,313.3,2.1,247.6,260.4,118.9,199.9,277,103.1,150.5,339.2,35.6,14.7,24.9])
F =   np.array([0.61745,0.43462,0.60387,0.56595,0.48926,0.55615,0.54351,0.64069,0.54228,0.51716,0.39157,0.51831,0.7053,0.62769,0.21159,0.29964,0.52126,0.53656,0.575,0.40306,0.60471])

relphi = np.abs(azs-azv)

thetas = np.deg2rad(thetas)
thetav = np.deg2rad(thetav)
relphi = np.deg2rad(relphi)


#  Compute the trigonometric functions:
coss = np.abs (np.cos(thetas))
cosv = np.cos(thetav)
sins = np.sqrt(1.0 - coss * coss)
sinv = np.sqrt(1.0 - cosv * cosv)
cosp = -np.cos(relphi)
tans = sins / coss
tanv = sinv / cosv
csmllg = coss * cosv + sins * sinv * cosp
bigg = np.sqrt(tans * tans + tanv * tanv - 2.0 * tans * tanv * cosp)


# Function to solve
def fun(x):
    return x[0] * ((coss * cosv) ** (x[1] - 1.0)) * ((coss + cosv) ** (x[1] - 1.0)) * (1.0 - x[2] * x[2]) / ((1.0 + x[2] * x[2] + 2.0 * x[2] * csmllg) ** (1.5) + 1e-12) * (1.0 + ((1 - x[0]) / (1.0 + bigg))) - F


# Find unknown x[0], x[1], x[2]
```

Comment: Do you want to mimize `F` or solve a nonlinear equation?

Comment: I would like to solve the nonlinear equation.